# Hold down button to give option to save as ringtone?

Tags: java, android, xml, button

I've looking for an answer for this question but no one really gives a clear answer on what code should be or look like. I've created am android app that plays sounds when you click a button but I'd like the use to have to option when they hold down on the button a display comes up where they can download or save as ringtone. Does anyone know how you would go about doing this?

Here's my code:

```
 MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button Bus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
    Bus.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Uri p1 = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() +
                    "/" + R.raw.bus);
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, p1);
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }

    });
```

and my xml:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/jay"
        android:shadowColor="#00FF00"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="10"
        android:text="@string/b1"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
```

Thanks, I'd really appreciate any help on this issue!

Comment: let me know if its helpful..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

theres is

```
Button.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //your code here with this you do anything manually
            return false; 
        }
    });
```

**Second Approach**
you can and also can register your button for context menu in oncreate or onstart or onresume

```
Context.registerForContextMenu(Button);
```

then you create a context menu.. and handle clicks there..

```
 @Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.playlist, menu);
}
```

**creating your context item selection**

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.download:
        //code to download
        break;
    case R.id.save:         
        //code to save
        break;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

**your playlist menu xml file**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/save"
    android:title="save playlist"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/download"        
    android:title="download playlist"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: the setOnLongClickListener work well but I'm just unsure what code i should write inside of its parameters

Comment: what are you mean elaborate... and the second way is quite direct to your problem..

Comment: Got it mate Sorry for being such a dumb ass, pretty new to this android coding thing.